# How can I customize the header layout of a dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

In Android, is it possible to customize the header layout (the icon + a text) layout of a dialog? Or can I just set a custom string value of the title text?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's possible to change the header of the Dialog if you set a custom layout for both the dialog and the header.  I've only ever used this method to remove the header entirely, but this ought to work for a custom header:

```
dialog = new Dialog(context);
Window window = dialog.getWindow();
window.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.my_dialog_layout);
window.setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.my_custom_header);
```

This is all a tad more complicated (as you have to setup the dialog's layout as well) but it's easier than subclassing Dialog.

Answer (score 1):

the original Dialog class seems to lack the ability to set an icon, but you can easily extend AlertDialog and set a custom view (the same you would use for your Dialog instance), you just need something like this

```
 class MyDialog extends AlertDialog {
     public MyDialog(Context ctx) {
        super(ctx);
        LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = factory.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
        setView(view);
        setTitle("MyTitle");
        setIcon(R.drawable.myicon);
     }
 }
```